# Cannot edit Deployment Connections when given rights through a Permission Set

Tags: deployment, permissions, change-set

The default System Administrator profile does not allow for creation of Change Sets and Deployment Connections. At one time we set up a clone of System Adminstrator with the following permissions ticked on

- Create & Upload Change Sets
- Deploy Change Sets

This works to overcome an odd oversight in the System Administrator profile.  But we wanted something a little more modular so we created a Permission Set with the same permissions ticked on and assigned it to our System Admins.  The problem we see now is that they can read but not edit Deployment Connections.

I dumped the Profile objects from the org (via DataLoader)and compared the base System Admin profile with the modified profile that allows editing of Deployment Connections.  The only differences were expected

- PERMISSIONSINBOUNDMIGRATIONTOOLSUSER set to true
- PERMISSIONSOUTBOUNDMIGRATIONTOOLSUSER set to true

Did the same thing with the Permission Sets and found that the exact same changes.  But it doesn't work.  Is it possible that there is something else I need to set up in the Permission Set to allow editing of the Deployment Connection?

Comment: Weird; in our org, created Feb 2012 (Spring '12), the standard System Admin profile has these enabled.

Comment: As an FYI I reproduced this odd behavior in my org.

Comment: Its not an exact science - we look after a number of orgs going back several years and while all of these have the permission on the system administrator profile, it is not editable for around half of them so we've had to clone.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please file a case with support and reference this stackexchange thread so that when it's escalated to my team in salesforce R&D, we'll know where it came from. Thanks!

Comment: Case 08466927 has been created.

Comment: Hi Chet - the case is showing as closed/resolved. Did you get a resolution to this issue?

Comment: Adam, we received prompt turn around on this request and the problem has been resolved in our org.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that this is another Just The Way It (Doesn't) Work situation.  A colleague tipped me off to [this developerforce board post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/System-Administrator-Profile-doesn-t-have-all-permissions/td-p/436879) that describes the same problem (deep in the thread) and alleges Summer '12 was the start of this misbehavior.

Comment: Double bonus points for "Just the Way It (Doesn't) Work", up there with "Working as designed: broken"

Answer (score 1):

The issue with permission sets not allowing this behavior is definitely a defect.  I have filed a bug accordingly and requested that it be fixed for the Spring '13 release.  However, it's not entirely up to me when it's fixed.  If it's important to you, I suggest you file a case and reference bug 1504836 in your case.

Comment: We already received a fix in our org for this problem.